# Remmina window doesn't fit on my screen

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I'm using Remmina 0.9.99.1 to connect to a Windows machine via VNC.
However, the Remmina window is way too large for my own screen, particularly in the vertical direction. I tried going to the advanced settings and changing the window scale and though it does help, I still can't see the full Desktop of my Windows machine. I can't reach the menu bar of the Windows Machine, it's completely out of view.
Is it possible to scale it? Or are there better alternatives out there?

Answer (score 6):

After you connect to the Windows server, does pressing CTRL+S work? (the CTRL button on the *right* side of your keyboard). In any case, you should upgrade to the latest Remmina (much much better) with these three simple commands:

**sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next**

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp**